# Inequality involving the Möbius function

Tags: number-theory, mobius-function

Let $a$ be an integer such that $a>1$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and define the number $x_{m}$ by

$$x_{m}=\sum_{d|m}\mu(d)(-1)^{n}[a^{\frac{m/d}{(m/d,n)}}-1]^{(m/d,n)}$$

I must to proof that $x_{m}\neq 0, \text{for all} \ m$

**My Approach**  If $m$ is a prime number it is easy to see that:

$$x_{m}=(-1)^n[(a-1)^m-(a-1)], \ \text{if} \ m|n$$

and

$$x_{m}=(-1)^n[a^m-a], \ \text{if} \  m \ \text{not divide} \ n $$

and in both cases it is obvious that $x_{m}\neq 0$

Does anybody has a hint for the general case?

Comment: Use induction on $m$.